# How to create an Entity field that can be referencing to a different types of entities using Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I've the next scenraio:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stage")
public class Stage {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    String name;

    Blocks // ===> Should be a list of different blocks (BlockA, BlockB)
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "blockA")
public class BlockA implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    //some fileds

    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "BlockB")
public class BlockB {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    //some fileds

    //getters and setters
}
```

So as you can see the `blocks` field within the `stage` entity should have a list with different blocks,
but it can be any block (e.g: `BlockA`, `BlockB`) and each step can contain the same blocks in a different order.
Unfortunately, I just can't understand what is the best approach to achieve this requirement.
I also was thinking to create another table that each row will hold the relations between step and block, but again the blocks are basically different tables

The wanted result should be a JSON output that looks something like this:

```
{
    name: "step1",
    blocks: [
               {...blockA},
               {...blockB},
               {...blockC},
               {...blockA}
                .....
            ]
}
```

Comment: Usually you would have a parent class Block and BlockA, BlockB, BlockC would extends that class

Comment: @Guillaume thanks for you help. So the type of `blocks` wil be something like this `List<AbstractBlock> blocks` and all the blocks extend the `AbstractBlock`? And how i'll know what are the blocks that are associated to the steps?

Comment: From what I understand I would suggest that the Stage has a list of steps instead of a list of blocks. The steps can have a list of blocks

Comment: sorry, i've ment `stages` not `steps`. i don't have steps

Comment: @Anna: if you go the way of creating a common superclass for all blocks, then you would have to use inheritance with a fitting strategy, see [Entity Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html). I'd probably choose `InheritanceType.JOINED` or `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` so that JPA/Hibernate can use a single foreign key to map

Comment: @Anna Unrelated, yet you might find it useful: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/kxfzamcs/72/